# Create Azure VM using java

Tags: java, azure, virtual-machine

How can we create a virtual machine in Azure using java?
I have an existing VM snapshot in azure portal. I want to create VM using that snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create the Azure VM no matter from which, you should have the image or disk. So first of all, you must create the image from the snapshot. And then create the Azure VM as usual from the image through.

For example, you can create Windows VM follow the steps in [Create and manage Windows VMs in Azure using Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/java). But you should make a change of the functions.

from **withLatestWindowsImage**

If the image is managed: into **withWindowsCustomImage(String customImageId)**

If the image is unmanaged: into **withStoredWindowsImage(String imageUrl)**

For more details, see [Azure SDK for Java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/18e9a4b927fafc64349de742ccd2f546da9c653b/archive/azure-mgmt-compute/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/management/compute/VirtualMachine.java).